# Zip thousand files in php - memory leak

Tags: php, memory-leaks, zip, out-of-memory

I have to zip search results containing maximum 10000 files, with an approximate dimension of far more than 1Gb.

I create a zip archive and read every file in a for loop whit fread and add the resulting file to the archive.
I never finished adding files because of this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1257723 bytes)
```

but I don't think adding 1Gb or more to the memory_limit value of php.ini could be a solution, because memory resources are limited.

Because of the zip file will stay in memory until it will be closed (or so I read in another question), I made a way to create a series of zip file of 50Mb to avoid the memory leak. But even if the php script create another file zip, it will stop with the same PHP Fatal error on the same file (the 174th).

Why?
Am I doing something wrong?
Any help will be appreciated.
Here is a code snippet of the file creation

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$nomeZipFile = "../tmp/" . $title . ".zip";

for ($x = 0; $x < count($risultato); $x++) {
    $numFiles = 0;
    $dir = '../tmp';
    if (file_exists($nomeZipFile)) {
        if (filesize($nomeZipFile) > 52428800) {
            // filename count
            if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
                while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
                    if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir . $file))
                        $numFiles++;
                }
            }
            $nomeZipFile = '../tmp/' . $title . $numFiles . '.zip';
            $res = $zip->open($nomeZipFile, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
        } else {
            $res = $zip->open($nomeZipFile, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
        }
    } else {
        $res = $zip->open($nomeZipFile, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
    }
    ...
    // adding file
    $fileDownload = "";
    $fDownload = fopen($kt_response->message, "r"); // the file is downloaded though a webservice
    while(!feof($fDownload)) { $fileDownload .= fread($fDownload, 1024); flush(); }
    $zip->addFromString(filename, $fileDownload);
....
$zip->close();
}
```

Comment: I think a different approach should be used: copy the files into one subdirectory, and use a command line zip tool to compress that directory, remove it after finish, and let the user download that compressed file...

Comment: Rather than use ZipARchive, which builds the zip file "in memory", you might need to consider using a zip stream writer like http://pablotron.org/software/zipstream-php/

Comment: also: you should use $zip->close() and also fclose when you try to create several smaller files

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add that at the end of the for loop ther is a $zip->close();

Comment: Not sure memory-leaks is a suitable tag for this? But I might be wrong.

Comment: @Anders - it's pretty common to find PHP developers using the term "memory leaks" to mean "uses lots of memory".... you and I know that's not a memory leak, but you get used to the term being abused by PHP developers